# visual studio android api version not available after SDK is installed

Tags: android, visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2022

Trying to install api 34 android 14 on visual studio 2022. I can install the newest SDK but it is not a selection option for the android project. Also when trying to add a new simulator with that api version its not available either. Any ideas how to get visual studio to recognize that I have the new SDK installed? Any ideas what I am supposed to do?

[image: SDKinstalled]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I'm afraid this is the reason:

> Xamarin support will end on May 1, 2024 for all Xamarin SDKs including Xamarin.Forms. **Android API 34 and Xcode 15 SDKs** (iOS and iPadOS 17, macOS 14) will be the final versions Xamarin will target from existing Xamarin SDKs (i.e. no new APIs are planned).

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin

Game over, we need to switch to MAUI
X-(

Comment: `we need to switch to MAUI` this is not the whole truth, luckily - xamarin forms apps must switch to MAUI, but xamarin android apps should switch to net-android

Answer (score 0):

What you are downloading is the SDK for Android, that is why it is not seen in the list of the emulator. You have to download the image corresponding to API 34 when you create the device to emulate. The image for emulator and SDK for Android version are two differents things.

Comment: hmm can you explain? where do I download the images? The screenshot shows 3 api34 images that were downloaded? Why can I not select API 34 to compile against with just the SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

Good news!
You still can target Android API 34, iOS 17, iPadOS 17 according to this post:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-rc-2/#bonus-2-xcode-15-and-android-api-34

Regarding the android emulator, I found API 34 at the bottom in Unsupported section of Android Device Manager
([Unsupported section picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr6Ae.png)).

Not really sure though that Emulator will run with Xamarin project, but for MAUI project it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Android 34 is only available as a target Android version when the target framework is set to .Net 8 for the project. Once I changed this, Android 34 became an option as the target Android version (assuming the SDK is installed).

Just to clarify as to Xamarin, it is not dead, its just Xamarin.Forms that has been decommissioned and replaced by MAUI. If you just use Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android there is no need to migrate projects to MAUI, they are now integrated directly into .Net starting with .Net 6 as Android, iOS, and Mac for .NET.

Comment: Do you mean on the Andoid project?
Where might I ask are you setting that?

Comment: @AntDC its set in the .csproj file on the Android project. I had to upgrade the target framework from .net7 to .net8 in order to target Android 34.

`<TargetFramework>net8.0-android34.0</TargetFramework>`