does Xamarin support android 14
Xamarin application does not allow to upload photo in Samsung Galaxy S23.
Even application version is also not visible.
My application is targeting android SDK API version 33 but Samsung Galaxy S23
using android 14 (android SDK API version 34).
(https://i.sstatic.net/gYYzSzuI.png)
Already READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED permission is allow in this application
"AndroidManifest.xml" file.
(https://i.sstatic.net/DdpDWmf4.png)
Please help to suggest any solution or feedback. Is there any possible way to resolve this issue?

we can't help you if you don't post the relevant code

This issue is not related to code, Its is just some permission issue in android 14 in Samsung Galaxy S23. I already attached snapshot of manifest file.
I did some analysis and I found some blog and also checked Xamarin document, Might be it doesn't support android 14.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650044/visual-studio-android-api-version-not-available-after-sdk-is-installed
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin
Please let me know if any alternate way for fixing this issue.

I need to see the code to know what path you are writing to

Even though Xamarin.Android support ended 1st May, you can still update a project to Android 14. All you need to do is update your manifest to
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

You will get warnings (XA1008, XA4218) when building, but they can be ignored. I've published apps to Google Play without problems. My apps are limited to minSDK 25. I've got no idea if you can still use 21 - but I doubt it.
Your permissions wont be accepted though, but they wouldn't have been with Android 13 either. You need to read up on the changes to permissions (scoped storage) with Android 10,11,12 through to Android 13.
The following are links to various articles you may find helpful.
https://medium.com/swlh/sample-for-android-storage-access-framework-aka-scoped-storage-for-basic-use-cases-3ee4fee404fc
https://www.zoftino.com/how-to-create-browse-files-option-in-android
https://mateuszteteruk.pl/how-to-use-android-storage-access-framework-with-example
https://thedroidlady.com/2020-08-24-android-scoped-storage-demystified
